# "Например" в сложных предложениях: может ли перед ним быть тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вводные-слова, перечисление

Здесь (и не только здесь) уже говорили о простых случаях с обособлением слова "например". Напомню на всякий:

1) бывают присоединяемые конструкции, то есть обособленные обороты,  где вообще запятая после "например" не нужна ("Православные святые, например Серафим Саровский, считали себя очень грешными людьми");

2) когда "например" не входит в целый оборот, а является единичным вводным словом, оно обособляется с двух сторон, тут тоже вопросов нет ("На фоне вас всех Маша, например, выглядит не сильно вредной");

3) иногда "например" стоит перед кучей однородных членов, там образуется двоеточие ("Я знаю много инженеров, например: Вася, Петя, Коля").

Я зависла на сложном предложении и теряюсь.

Есть такое предложение:

> Есть в нем и представители технических профессий – например,
>   инженеры-технологи;
>   разработчики мобильных приложений, занимающиеся конструированием кроссплатформенных программ с нуля; сотрудники техподдержки, консультирующие пользователей по телефону;
>   техники-аналитики.

Возможно ли возникновение тире перед "например"? Само собой, можно убрать тире и поставить после "например" двоеточие: "Есть в нём и представители технических профессий, например: разработчики, инженеры и т.д.". Но если требуется интонационная пауза после "профессий", возникновение тире становится понятным. Однако тогда непонятно, как адекватно обособить "например", нужны ли какие-то ещё знаки, требуется ли запятая после "профессий".

Помогите разобраться и расскажите, чем обусловлена с точки зрения правил авторская расстановка знаков, если она верная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном примере однозначно можно поставить тире. И это лучший вариант, если автор не желает большой перечислительной паузы при постановке двоеточия, так как после идёт большой фрагмент с примерами. Тире можно поставить везде, где подставляется слово "это":
*Есть в нем и представители технических профессий – это, например, инженеры-технологи...*

Такое тире обычно ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными. Но иногда, по аналогии, ставится между подлежащим и дополнением.